# How to optionally reference another request in a composite request?

Tags: rest-api, api, composite

I need to reference a third to one of two other requests. So there's a `Publication_Subscription__c` which has two properties:

1. `Contact__c`
2. `Lead__c`

Always one of both exist and the other is `null`. So it's like a conditional (Left) join. I need to use a composite request to find the contact/lead with a given e-mail and to return all publication-subscriptions which have either that lead or contact assigned.

I have tried this:

post url: `.../services/data/v53.0/composite`

```
{
  "allOrNone": "false",
  "compositeRequest": [
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/services/data/v53.0/query?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+Contact+WHERE+Email+=+'jon.doe%40gmail.com'+AND+RecordTypeId+=+'0121x0000030snIAAQ'+LIMIT+1",
      "referenceId": "CurrentContact"
    },
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/services/data/v53.0/query?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+Lead+WHERE+Email+=+'jon.doe%40gmail.com'+AND+RecordTypeId+=+'0121x0000030snIAAQ'+LIMIT+1",
      "referenceId": "CurrentLead"
    },
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/services/data/v53.0/query?q=SELECT+Lead__c,+Contact__c,+Id,+Subscription_Status__c,+Subscription_Date_dt__c,+ExtId__c,+Name+FROM+Publication_Subscription__c+WHERE+((Contact__c+=+'@{CurrentContact.records[0].Id}')+OR+Lead__c+=+'@{CurrentLead.records[0].Id}')",
      "referenceId": "Publications"
    }
  ]
}
```

But i get a 400 in the request that doesn't return a record:

> "message": "Invalid reference specified. No value for
> CurrentLead.records[0].Id found in CurrentLead. Provided referenceId
> ('CurrentLead.records[0].Id') must start with a letter or a number,
> and it can contain only letters, numbers and underscores ('_')."

How can i modify the query to ensure that the related query returned at least one record(i tried `@{CurrentContact.totalSize} > 0` but it didn't work either: "unexpected token: '1'").

Answer (score 2):

One option in this case is to send two separate subrequests. One subrequest would search for Publications using the Contact while the other would use the Lead.

Then you'd need to check which of those two subresponses has `httpStatusCode == 200` and which has `httpStatusCode == 400`.

Your request:

```
{
  "allOrNone": "false",
  "compositeRequest": [
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/services/data/v53.0/query?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+Contact+WHERE+Email+=+'jon.doe%40gmail.com'+AND+RecordTypeId+=+'0121x0000030snIAAQ'+LIMIT+1",
      "referenceId": "CurrentContact"
    },
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/services/data/v53.0/query?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+Lead+WHERE+Email+=+'jon.doe%40gmail.com'+AND+RecordTypeId+=+'0121x0000030snIAAQ'+LIMIT+1",
      "referenceId": "CurrentLead"
    },
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/services/data/v53.0/query?q=SELECT+Lead__c,+Contact__c,+Id,+Subscription_Status__c,+Subscription_Date_dt__c,+ExtId__c,+Name+FROM+Publication_Subscription__c+WHERE+Contact__c+=+'@{CurrentContact.records[0].Id}'",
      "referenceId": "PublicationsFromContact"
    },
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/services/data/v53.0/query?q=SELECT+Lead__c,+Contact__c,+Id,+Subscription_Status__c,+Subscription_Date_dt__c,+ExtId__c,+Name+FROM+Publication_Subscription__c+WHERE+Lead__c+=+'@{CurrentLead.records[0].Id}'",
      "referenceId": "PublicationsFromLead"
    }
  ]
}
```

And a possible response:

```
{
    "compositeResponse": [
        {
            "body": {
                // No contact found
                "records": []
            },
            "httpStatusCode": 200,
            "referenceId": "CurrentContact"
        },
        {
            "body": {
                // Some lead found
                "records": [{ ... }]
            },
            "httpStatusCode": 200,
            "referenceId": "CurrentLead"
        },
        {
            "body": {
                // Some error message
            },
            "httpStatusCode": 400,
            "referenceId": "PublicationsFromContact"
        },
        {
            "body": {
                // Your publications from the lead
            },
            "httpStatusCode": 200,
            "referenceId": "PublicationsFromLead"
        }
    ]
}
```