# Composite Request - Conditional reference

Tags: rest-api, api, composite

I have a basic composite request to Insert a case and fill the conatactId based on Email.
Where no contact was found the 2nd sub request failed because the reference does not exist. Is there a way the conditionally reference the contactId in the 2 sub request ?

```
    {
    "compositeRequest": [
        {
            "method": "GET",
            "url": "/services/data/v51.0/query?q=SELECT+id,Email+FROM+Contact+WHERE+Email='testmail@test.com' ",
            "referenceId": "refContact"
        },
        {
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/Case",
            "referenceId": "refCase",
            "body": {
                "Subject": "Subject",
                "Issue_Origin__c": "Dashboard",
                "Type": "Question",
                "Description": "Text",
                "SuppliedEmail": "test123@test.com",
                "SuppliedName": "Name",
                "SuppliedPhone": "0524567677",
                "ContactId": "@{refContact.records[0].Id}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Did you try using allOrNone flag ? -  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_allornone.htm
It will give successful response only when both requests are complete. That's essentially conditional i think.

Comment: @Rohit but still want to create a case if no contact was found

Comment: In that case, you can just create a case via composite api & link with contact in  apex trigger. Does not look possible via api.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to optionally reference another request in a composite request?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/367013/how-to-optionally-reference-another-request-in-a-composite-request)

Comment: Thanks @identigral it does not answer to my question

Comment: @Rohit indeed it does not seems to be possible, I will split the composite into 2 different request to implement the conditional set of the Contact

Comment: @RaphaelD : Yes , 2 requests would work but I just thought that handling it in trigger would have been easier.

Comment: @RaphaelD did you ever find a single-composite-request solution to this?